# using dynamic value in tailwindcss in react/nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

creating a span element which moves throughout the day, depending on the current time that element should be x% down of it's parent div.

snippet of relevant code:

```
const [timePercentage, setTimePercentage] = useState(timeToPercentage());
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTimePercentage(timeToPercentage());
    }, 60000);
    clearInterval(interval);
}, [time]);
```

tsx:

```
return(
<div className="relative grid flex-1 mt-2 text-sm">
        <span className={`w-full h-[.5px] bg-red-600 absolute top-[${timePercentage}%]`} />
</div>
)
```

the issue is react is not acknowledging this as a percentage. using chrome's inspector I am able to see the percentage ex. top-[50%] but the span does not move. If I were to manually change state to 50 Ex.( const [timePercentage, setTimePercentage] = useState(50) ). it would work. but timePercentage type if also a number.

helper functions (TS):

```
function getTime(): [number, number] {
const time = new Date();
const hours = time.getHours();
const mins = time.getMinutes();
return [hours, mins];
}

function timeToPercentage(): number {
const [hours, mins] = getTime();
const minsPercentage = mins / 60;
return ((hours + minsPercentage) / 24) * 100;
}
```

Comment: Use `style` attribute instead. Otherwise you have to [safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) every possible `top` class

Comment: yea, that is the best option

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your case.
You should not pass data to class like that: `top-[${timePercentage}%]`, because TailwindCSS will not handle this type of dynamic classes.

I think, that the way to solve this issue is to return in `timeToPercntage()` a className, i. e. `return "top-${((hours + minsPercentage) / 24) * 100}"`.

[Explanation in Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)